# Did Romulus and Remus have other names?

Tags: history, example-request, names, roman-culture

Throughout Classical times, Romans would often have several names: one person might be identified by praenomen, nomen gentilicum, cognomen, agnomen, signum, and patronymic, all together.

Were Roman historical figures like Romulus and Remus ever "retrofitted" with these different types of names? Or did they only have the single name, since they predated the system of tria nomina?

(I'm looking specifically for an example of a Latin author attributing other names to monarchy-era figures, if possible, or else saying explicitly that these figures had no other names.)